# Change Data Capture - SQL SERVER?

Tags: sql-server, change-data-capture

I have a question about SQL SERVER ?

Change Data Capture (CDC)

I apply the CDC process in which the user DELETE, UPDATE, INSERT operations do not have that.
So, how can I get the information of the user name?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a trigger to log the operation and the user name. Try the function `SUSER_NAME()` or `SUSER_ID()`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to have an extra column in your tracked tables, that store a user ID that commited the current change.
When you look at the history of the table it will store each row with the appropriate user ID.